# Google OAUTH2 not working with Symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to implement social login with google in Symfony 5.4 running PHP 8.0. I am using the oauth2-client-bundle for the job.
I follow the exact instructions they give [here](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle) for the facebook code but replace with google. This is my code so far

GoogleController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class GoogleController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * Link to this controller to start the "connect" process
     *
     * @Route("/connect/google", name="connect_google_start")
     */
    public function connectAction(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry)
    {
        // will redirect to google!
        return $clientRegistry
            ->getClient('google') // key used in config/packages/knpu_oauth2_client.yaml
            ->redirect([
                'email'
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * After going to google, you're redirected back here
     * because this is the "redirect_route" you configured
     * in config/packages/knpu_oauth2_client.yaml
     *
     * @Route("/connect/google/check", name="connect_google_check")
     */
    public function connectCheckAction(Request $request, ClientRegistry $clientRegistry)
    {
        // leave this method blank and create a Guard authenticator
    }
}
```

GoogleAuthenticator:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;

// your user entity
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\OAuth2Authenticator;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GoogleUser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\SelfValidatingPassport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;

class GoogleAuthenticator extends OAuth2Authenticator implements AuthenticationEntrypointInterface
{
    private ClientRegistry $clientRegistry;
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    private RouterInterface $router;

    public function __construct(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->clientRegistry = $clientRegistry;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        // continue ONLY if the current ROUTE matches the check ROUTE
        return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'connect_google_check';
    }


    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $client = $this->clientRegistry->getClient('google');

        $accessToken = $this->fetchAccessToken($client);

        return new SelfValidatingPassport(
            new UserBadge($accessToken->getToken(), function () use ($accessToken, $client)
            {
                /** @var GoogleUser $googleUser */
                $googleUser = $client->fetchUserFromToken($accessToken);

                $email = $googleUser->getEmail();

                // 1) have they logged in with Google before? Easy!
                $existingUser = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['googleId' => $googleUser->getId()]);

                if ($existingUser)
                {
                    return $existingUser;
                }

                // 2) do we have a matching user by email?
                $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

                // 3) Maybe you just want to "register" them by creating
                // a User object
                $user->setGoogleId($googleUser->getId());
                $this->entityManager->persist($user);
                $this->entityManager->flush();

                return $user;
            })
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        // change "app_homepage" to some route in your app
        $targetUrl = $this->router->generate('homepage');

        return new RedirectResponse($targetUrl);

        // or, on success, let the request continue to be handled by the controller
        //return null;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        $message = strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData());

        return new Response($message, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication is needed, but it's not sent.
     * This redirects to the 'login'.
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null): Response
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(
            '/connect/', // might be the site, where users choose their oauth provider
            Response::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
        );
    }
}
```

security.yaml:

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\FacebookAuthenticator
                - App\Security\GoogleAuthenticator

            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider

            form_login:
                # "app_login" is the name of the route created previously
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                default_target_path: /
                enable_csrf: true

            remember_me:
                always_remember_me: true
                path: /
                secret: '%kernel.secret%' # required
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds

            logout:
                path: app_logout

            entry_point: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
         - { path: ^/club/*, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

knpu_oauth2_client.yaml:

```
knpu_oauth2_client:
    clients:
        # configure your clients as described here: https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle#configuration
        facebook_main:
            # this will be one of the supported types
            type: facebook
            client_id: '%env(OAUTH_FACEBOOK_ID)%'
            client_secret: '%env(FACEBOOK_SECRET)%'
            # the route that you're redirected to after
            # see the controller example below
            redirect_route: connect_facebook_check
            redirect_params: {}
            graph_api_version: v2.12
        google:
            # this will be one of the supported types
            type: google
            client_id: '%env(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)%'
            client_secret: '%env(GOOGLE_SECRET)%'
            # the route that you're redirected to after
            # see the controller example below
            redirect_route: connect_google_check
            redirect_params: {}
```

When I start the authentication process the user is redirect to the google page where he must select a google account. However once he selects an account the loader keeps loading and nothing happens. I need to restart my local server to run the app again.(I am guessing some infinite loop problem.)
Can anyone help me? Thank you!

The code executes until  `$accessToken = $this->fetchAccessToken($client);` and there it gets stuck. Anyone has any idea what can cause such behaviour?